# Is there a term in English to characterize the male/female bipolarity of major and minor tonality?

Tags: theory, terminology, history

Is there any association of dur and moll with *male* and *female* like in European compositions to define the polarity of major and minor tonalities in orchestral works like symphonies?

**Edit:**

To avoid any misconceptions I want to emphasize 
the terms  *dur* and *moll* are neutral or used without article. My question concerns the qualifying them as feminine or masculine by their character in sound or historical use.

Comment: I wonder if Guido is right in his  comment  on my answer to this question:
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/100837/what-is-the-word-to-describe-the-aspect-of-a-chord-being-either-minor-or-major/100845?noredirect=1#comment174369_100845

Comment: What values can 'tone-gender' take?  Male/female, or just major/minor?

Comment: I've never heard of major or minor being associated with gender. The German expression is new to me, and doesn't match any association I have.

Comment: You are getting confused by the fact that the German word 'Geschlecht' can be used in both cases. English speakers would never think of  'gender' in the context of tonality.

Comment: I've often wondered how speakers of languages with gendered nouns can see an object for the first time and know what its gender is. It also seems likely that speakers of those languages see gender in places an English-only speaker would not, like in major vs minor.

Comment: The question _assumes_ that major/minor can be characterized as male/female. I'd sooner see this recast as a question instead: _Can_ major/minor be characterized as male/female for speakers of languages that have non-gendered nouns?

Comment: I think the question in the title is very different from the question in the question body. The question title basically asks if there's a (single word) translation into English of the German word "Tongeschlecht". The answer is "no". When it comes to chords, the answer would be "chord quality". The question about the associations female-minor / male-major is a different one.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS: That's not how it works. Nobody sees an object for the first time and "knows" its gender. Only if you know the word for it, it may be possible to infer its gender from the word itself, but often even that isn't possible. So you depend on having heard the word in grammatical contexts that reveal its gender.

Comment: It is a theoretical and historical question. Already the ancient Greek associated the modes with gender characteristics. In harmony theory the scales and chords have been associated in music history with gender characteristic.   I know from music literature since my childhood that harmony (chords and scales) have always been used as bipolar symbolic gender characters in Sonatas, Concertos, Symphonies. Btw. the articles of Dur and Moll in German are neutral ...

Comment: @MattL. I had this discussion with a French colleague and he said he just "knew" what gender a thing was. Perhaps he was the one and only exception to the "nobody knows" rule?

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS: No rule, obviously, but I don't think we're talking about the same thing. The gender is not in the things, it's in the language, that's a fact. Why would different languages have different genders for the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Tongeschlecht* is one of those words that doesn't get translated very well (or easily) into English sources. Depending on context, it might refer to English language concepts of *genus* (e.g., referencing ancient Greek tetrachord tunings) or *mode* (whether major/minor or church modes) or (chord) *quality*.

In any case, none of these concepts are particularly gendered in modern English-language music theory.  The Susan McClary source you quote is from her general work critiquing the use of gender concepts in music.  (She wrote an entire book called *Feminine Endings* whose title was playing off of an old-fashioned set of terms for cadences that arrive on or off a beat.)  In general, largely because of her work and others, the artificial gendering of musical concepts has been under a great deal of scholarly criticism in recent decades, so it's very unlikely that the male/female gendering of chord qualities or keys would be received well.

Anyhow, this is one of the few places you will see this brought up in professional literature on music theory (generally in direct reference to the original German sources).  That's not to say that *no* English language theorists have used the male/female dichotomy in reference to major/minor duality, but those who do generally are assuming readers who are familiar with the original German sources that make this distinction.  I don't remember what Alex Rehding says about this in the book you mention (and I don't have my copy handy) -- my recollection off the top of my head is that gendered metaphors for tonality were a little more common in English-language theory in the 19th century (as well as the "natural"/"unnatural" rhetoric McClary mentions, which comes out of 18th-century concepts about the harmonic series and the derivation of major triads).  In general, the gendering of tonality (and related concepts, like male/female duality of sonata themes, the gendering of cadences already mentioned, etc.) is widely viewed with suspicion by modern English-language scholars as an artificial concept, so it hasn't gained wide currency in English.

Comment: That’s it! We shouldn’t forget that composers  and analysts who wrote about music also have been speculating and their theories have been opinion based. Meanwhile I’m also convinced that this dichotomy is characterizing the key and tonality of a piece or a melody and is not referred to single chords.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli: Yes, I don't mean at all to *criticize* these theories: they are a common development, particularly in languages that tend to use gender more freely than English. They are just metaphors that haven't found their way into English. And yes, I didn't mean to imply the term was only restricted to chords -- I know it's a broader sense of tonality.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to the original question cited in the comment above. And Guidot must have been right.

Answer (score 0):

In my studies I have not come across a gender designation concerning the quality of the Major/Minor keys. Instead, the quality is generally described as "Bright and Happy" for the Major keys and "Somber or Sad" in describing the Minor keys. However, since you posted this idea, it has started me thinking about trying to notice any gender specific aspects of Major and Minor keys. I don't know what word would be used to classify this kind of association, but I would understand what you were talking about if you were to refer to it as gender recognition. Since modes also have Major and minor aspects to them, it makes me wonder if these gender designations also apply to the modes?

Comment: how about *genus* than *gender*?

Comment: @Albrecht Hugli- Over here we hardly ever speak Latin whereas "gender" is easily understood.

Comment: so let's talk about sex?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_and_gender_distinction

*La distinction entre sexe et genre différencie le sexe (l'anatomie d'une personne, le système reproducteur, et les caractères sexuels secondaires) du genre, qui est une paire de rôles sociaux fondés sur le sexe de la personne (rôle de genre), rôles auxquels les personnes s'identifient ou non (identité de genre)*
What term do you use for the sex of the articles m. and f. in French (*le/la*) and *der/die*  in German?

Comment: Of course, in earlier times, the major third was *hard,* while the minor third was *soft.*

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli the application of "gender" to the concept formerly known only as "sex" is very recent.  Articles and other grammatical entities do not possess sex, only gender, and until a few decades ago, people and other biological entities did not possess gender, only sex.

Comment: So maybe I should use feminine and masculine instead of male and female? or yin and yang? Btw. also in the lexicon they describe moll=weiblich, dur=männlich:https://www.lernhelfer.de/schuelerlexikon/musik/artikel/tonarten#

Comment: @Albrecht Hugli- I think you're on to something here. I'd probably understand what you're talking about if those terms were used in a discussion. However I might still question why you might classify that quality as being masculine or feminine.

Comment: translation: "The Latin durus means "hard" and also sounds like it in comparison with minor. Major is the “male” of the two tone genders common in tonal music.

Comment: @skinny peacock: that's not my idea. It has been in the mind of  music theorists for hundreds of years - like the mode characteristics. I don't believe that minor and major are bipolar, but I was trying to find the English term for "Tongeschlecht" as it is used in music history and music theory. And I'm wondering why there is not an analog term in English to describe the quality of major and minor. (s. the other question).

Answer (score 0):

It would be surprising to me that so much of European theory (e.g. Hugo Riemann, Arnold Schoenberg, Willi Apel) has been translated to English and is well known in American music literature - but this terminology of a *male and female* principle of tonality and harmony shouldn't have been translated ...

If I look up for the translation of "das Tongeschlecht" the translation is **mode**.

https://www.dict.cc/?s=Tongeschlecht

and it says:

> The word **Tongeschlecht** came up in the 18th century as a
>   translation word for *genos*. In Greek music theory, this term included
>   diatonic, chromatic and harmonica. However, these can only be equated
>   to a limited extent with our current terms of diatonic, chromatic and
>   harmonic.

But now I want to know what is to find in the English editon of  the Riemann's Dictionnary!

and what articles have been  published about this subject:

Musical Polarity: Major and Minor -

*stable- 
music, whereas minor is artificial, intelligible only in subordination to major. ... **pairs forms a conceptual whole: day-night, male-female, inhaling-exhal**.* ...

https://www.jstor.org/stable/24617779?seq=1

Hugo Riemann and the Birth of Modern Musical Thoughtbooks.google.ch › books
**Tone relations ( Tonverwandtschaft ) , a term from modern speculative theory , which ... those of the same harmonic gender ( both major or minor )** whose principal tones are related to ... 79 , he finally offered 197 Glossary : Riemann ' s key terms.

Suchergebnisse
Webergebnisse

Susan McClary quotes A. Schönberg in her book:

[image]

[Reading Music: Selected Essays
von Susan McClary](https://books.google.ch/books?id=kiwxDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT146&lpg=PT146&dq=major%20minor%20music%20male%20female&source=bl&ots=Yj8MkP-HyR&sig=ACfU3U3OXEz-z0jH0k0b3Hdg2fhVGIWSHA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj71KzBvoPqAhXkwcQBHThpBoAQ6AEwBHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=major%20minor%20music%20male%20female&f=false)

Comment: It is always interesting to see how others view different aspects of music. I have to admit it's a new perspective to me.